# Does Golarion's Shadow Plane have any Good creatures?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, races, alignment, golarion

Paizo bends over backwards to express that being next to the Positive Energy Plane doesn't make you good, nor does being near the Negative Energy Plane make you bad. Heck, they even list the Shadow Plane as mildly-neutral alignment. But I have spent days going through Pathfinder bestiaries and have found a bunch of evil native or frequent-visitor races, plenty of evil undead, a couple neutral races (Shae), a few unaligned animal-intelligence creatures (Gloomwings), and two player races (Wayang and Fetchling) that can technically be any alignment...but no actual good races.

Do any good races either live in or frequently visit the Shadow Plane on Golarion?

Comment: It's worth noting that the Shadow Plane is a transitive plane, existing as the ["barrier between the Material Plane and the Negative Energy Plane"](https://starfinderwiki.com/sf/Shadow_Plane). Many creatures "visit" the Shadow Plane with spells and abilities like [Shadow Walk](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shadow-walk/) but don't necessarily hang out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in substantial numbers, but the same is true of Golarion.

Take [Shadow Absalom](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Shadow_Absalom)'s population (the biggest city on the plane):

- 51k Fetchlings
- 25k Material plane humanoids
- 10k D'ziriaks
- 6k Intelligent Undead
- 10k Others

No good creatures are listed, but also if we look at the same stats for [Absalom](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Absalom), we similarly find no good creatures listed.

There are likely fewer on the shadow plane than there are on Golarion, due to it's association with Zon Kuthon and the Negative Energy Plane. Paizo may have been clear that there are practical and good uses for Negative Energy, but also they've been clear that it is what powers undead, and that good undead are *incredibly* rare -- going by adventure paths they are rarer even than good demons and devils (this is because undead have the afterlife as an option, and secondly because Positive Energy is the force of creation and creativity - things Undead lack, which makes seeing things from other perspectives hard -- this is well explored in the Pathfinder Tales: Bloodbound novel, and the nature of Positive Energy is touched on in Pathfinder Tales: The Redemption Engine).

In general good species are less frequently listed or described in Bestiaries, Adventure Paths, and other books than evil creatures. This is because players are less likely to encounter them, and even less likely to encounter them in such a way that the GM needs their stats.

There are likely some - particularly as it is a planar trading hub*. But probably fewer than for Golarion.

*From the wiki, Shadow Absalom's main trading partner is Absalom - and the ruler of Shadow Absalom places a high importance on maintaining trade.

Comment: Could you provide some citation for "good demons or devils being more common than good undead"?

Comment: James Jacobs in an interview on YouTube ... probably in a Pathfinder Friday. I'll try and find it when I have more time, but it may not be trivial to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the 56 source books including the Bestiary 1-4 and the Adventure Paths, 20 creatures are a match when one look for entries with the "Shadow Plane" environment. And out of those 20, none is any alignment of good.

The Bestiary 6 is about Evil creatures, so you're not likely to find anything fitting your criterias there.

The Bestiary 5 looked promising, but after skimming through the 300 creatures in there, I found none that is Good and living in the Shadow Plane.

My personal hunch is that you're out of luck and while the Shadow Plane is not inherently evil, it was not intended as a fun place for vacations when it was designed and is since filled mostly by monsters.

What Isaac pointed is true, you *will* find Good aligned *individuals*, but there is no source of a definitely good race/species from there.